# SQL query to select results from two different tables dependent on values in column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having to learn PostgreSQL for my job, and I'm asking this on my personal computer, so I'll provide conceptual scenario versus a direct copy/paste of code if that's fine. This task is being performed in Lambda, and has a timeout of 15 minutes.

I basically need a query that says:

1. For record #1 in table firstTable ft, if column Origin and Destination in firstTable ft = Origin and Destination in secondTable st
2. It searches through columns A-Z, and if any value in column A, column B, column C all the way through column Z *from secondTable st* have a value > 0, grab those specific columns in particular
3. BUT I only want to grab the first 3 columns that have data with a value > 0, and if *none* do, just return 0
4. I then was to sum up the values of the 3 columns grabbed

I was able to do this in a memory-intesive way by storing the data and looping through both tables finding records that meet the conditions, but I feel like a SQL query would be more effecient, but I have 0, absolutely 0 SQL experience. I think I should add there are no NULL values in the data

And I promise this scenario was made because I feel like it would be better than explaining the actual tables/values/ etc, it's not out of laziness lol.

select st.column A, st.column B, etc st.column Z
FROM firstTable ft, secondTable st
WHERE(essentially each individual column is greater than 0, but don't know how to properly write that)
LIMIT 3

Comment: Please update your question (with editable text) to show sample data for the tables involved and the result that you want to achieve based on that sample data; please ensure the sample data covers the various scenarios you've described

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, why is that necessary for a detailed hypothetical?

Comment: Because it would make your requirements easier to understand and ensure that anyone reading them has interpreted them correctly. However, it looks like what you want to achieve is not possibly in pure SQL so you'd have to write code (stored procedure) anyway. It's requirements 2&3 that are not possible as there is no way to code in SQL "stop when I've found 3 non-null columns"; this might be possible for a small number of columns and a CASE statement - but you have "3 from 26" combinations/permutations which is 1000s and I doubt a CASE statement would support this

Answer (score 0):

**1. `secondTable` with 2+27 columns named `origin`, `destination` and then `A` to
`Z`**

The issue here is to scan and analyse the 27 columns values in an efficient manner. One solution can be to convert the 27 columns into a single json object using the `to_json` function :

```
SELECT to_json(st.*) - 'origin' - 'destination' AS object
  FROM firstTable ft
 INNER JOIN secondTable st
    ON ft.origin = st.origin 
   AND ft.destination = st.destination
 LIMIT 1 ;
```

And then filter the result according to your criteria, using the `json_each` function in order to break down the json object and then order by asc the json keys and selecting the 3 first values > 0 :

```
SELECT l.origin, l.destination, s.result
  FROM 
     ( SELECT st.origin
            , st.destination
            , to_json(st.*) - 'origin' - 'destination' AS object
         FROM firstTable ft
        INNER JOIN secondTable st
           ON ft.origin = st.origin 
          AND ft.destination = st.destination
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS l
CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
    ( SELECT COALESCE(sum(v.value :: integer), 0) AS result
        FROM json_each(l.object) AS v(key, value)
       WHERE v.value :: integer > 0
       ORDER BY v.key ASC
       LIMIT 3
    ) AS r
```

**2. `secondTable` with 2+1 columns named `origin`, `destination` and `"a-z"` of type jsonb**

Having only one column called `"a-z"` of type jsonb instead of 27 columns may be relevant if most of the time only some of the columns are fulfilled. Column `"a-z"` contains a jsonb object whose keys correspond to the columns A-Z with a value. The query can be :

```
SELECT st.origin, st.destination, r.result
  FROM firstTable ft
 INNER JOIN secondTable st
    ON ft.origin = st.origin 
   AND ft.destination = st.destination
CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
    ( SELECT COALESCE(sum(v.value :: integer), 0) AS result
        FROM json_each(st."a-z") AS v(key, value)
       WHERE v.value :: integer > 0
       ORDER BY v.key ASC
       LIMIT 3
    ) AS r
LIMIT 1
```

**3. `secondTable` with 2+2 columns named `origin`, `destination`, `label`, `value`**

In this database design, there may be up to 27 rows for the same (origin, destination) with value A to Z in column `label` and the corresponding value in column `value`. The query can be :

```
SELECT l.origin, l.destination, sum(v.value) AS result
  FROM
     ( SELECT st.origin
            , st.destination
            , COALESCE((array_agg(st.value ORDER BY st.label ASC) FILTER (WHERE st.value > 0))[1:3], array[0]) AS arr
         FROM firstTable ft
        INNER JOIN secondTable st
           ON ft.origin = st.origin 
          AND ft.destination = st.destination
        GROUP BY st.origin, st.destination
        LIMIT 1
     ) AS l
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(l.arr) AS v(value)
 GROUP BY l.origin, l.destination
```

These solutions must be tested obviously.